# Did the Low Quality Posts filter change recently?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I had a few minutes and went through the Low Quality Posts. The filter worked really well, and it identified a bunch of low hanging fruit. I burned through 20 votes in about 4 or 5 minutes.

I've also noticed the Low Quality Posts queue has been a bit larger than normal lately.

Did the filter change recently?

Comment: Very strange, indeed. I am getting consecutive answers from different users with the message "check out..." and a link.

Answer (score 12):

Just regular users searching for old answers that might be NAA and then flagging them, which brings them into the queue.

For example, with [queries like this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201514/find-answers-to-flag) and [others](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=find+answers+to).